# Hibernate org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity

Tags: hibernate

I have the following entity which I can't map for some reason and I get "org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity" during run time

Human:

```
package abo;

public class Human {

private int id;
private String name;
public Human()
{

}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

}
```

mapping file Human.hbm.xml(in the same package):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 16:40:24 26/09/2015 by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="abo.Human" table="human">
        <id name="id" type="int">
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="name" type="java.lang.String">
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And now the hibernate configuration file(hibernate.cfg.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                         "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory name="">
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">blabla</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
  <property name="hibernate.default_schema">protein_tracker</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
  <mapping resource="abo/Human.hbm.xml"/>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How do you get the ServiceRegistry and SessionFactory instances?

I got the same error, but when I try this it works:

```
ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure().build();

SessionFactory sessionFactory = new MetadataSources( serviceRegistry ).buildMetadata().buildSessionFactory();
```

I get this from [Hibernate Getting Started Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/quickstart/html/#hibernate-gsg-tutorial-basic-test)

I'm working on an example similar to yours. I hope this help you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to write ein your example SessionFactory as the :

```
SessionFactory objSf = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need @Entity above your Human class to let Hibernate know it's to be mapped. You also need to add the package path and class name to you config file. Something like: 
            < mapping class="abo.Human"/>